# Detect whether there is an Internet connection available using Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How can I check wheather device has connected to internet using IBM Worklight

Comment: i dont know how to do that one.. iam new to mobile development

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Worklight provides the following API method: [WL.Device.getNetworkInfo](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.html%23getNetworkInfo)

For example, check for Internet connection on application startup and do actions based on the result.
In common\js\main.js:

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    WL.Device.getNetworkInfo(function (networkInfo) {
        alert (networkInfo.isNetworkConnected);
        if (networkInfo.isNetworkConnected) { // if true, then
            // connect to the Worklight Server or do something else...
        }
    });
```

IBM provides a Knowledge Center with complete API reference and more.
[Please review it](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNJXP/welcome.html).

Comment: You can use it wherever you need it. For example in wlCommonInit or in some other function. Depending on your need and scenario.

Comment: not clear Idan.. I want error message when app is opened check for internet and also when updating record also. when ever internet required der i required the checking internet connection

Comment: Then create a helper function that will do the above. Call this function whenever you want to invoke an adapter. If true, invoke the adapter. If false, show an error...